# supervisor starts the celery worker, spawn it and exits with status code (exit status 1; not expected)

Tags: django, ubuntu, rabbitmq, celery, supervisord

When I start the supervisor it starts celery and goes to RUNNING state, then after a few seconds restarts the celery worker. It continuously does this.

checked the supervisor log, seen that it spawned the worker with pid and goes to success and again goes to exited state.

tried with shutting down the supervisor and started again.

Please find the log of supervisor.log

```
2019-07-16 11:06:48,798 INFO exited: celeryd (exit status 1; not expected)
2019-07-16 11:06:42,539 INFO success: celeryd entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2019-07-16 11:06:48,798 INFO exited: celeryd (exit status 1; not expected)
```

I expect to run continuously and respond for the command what I give.

Comment: It appears as though celeryd is not starting correctly. Are the flags passed to celery correct? Is the configuration valid? Are there any permissions issues? Try increasing the verbosity level of celeryd's logging to see any issues it reports.

Answer (score 2):

Without the actual log from the worker it is very little we can do to help you. However, we can guide you how to find out what is going on:

1. Find out the exact line how supervisor runs the Celery worker.
2. Log in as user that supervisor uses to run the Celery worker (something like `sudo su - <celery user>` or similar).
3. Run manually your worker in the single mode (no `celery multi`!) with the DEBUG log-level (modify the command line to contain `-l debug`) and as foreground process (remove the -D flag from the command line, if you have it). The command to run Celery worker typically looks like: `celery -A projpackage.app worker -c 4 -l debug` but it can be much more complex.

After the third step you will be able to see a pretty verbose output from your worker, and will find out why it exits so early with a non-zero status.